# C# Discord Announcement Command, wont work

Tags: c#, request, discord

I'm very new to c# coding. Today I've been trying to start off by learning the basics of a discord bot. I have a couple base commands down but this one has stumped me. I'm trying to make a quick discord announce command..

It'd work like this -- !announce "hello how are you"

The bot would go to announcement channel and type out, "Announcement from NAMEHERE- hello how are you"

I have everything working perfect on this besides the fact I can only type out one word.. So if I did type out "hello how are you" it wouldn't say anything. But if I typed out "hello" it'd work perfect.

CODE

```
        commands.CreateCommand("announce").AddCheck((cm, u, ch) => u.ServerPermissions.Administrator).Parameter("announceMSG").Do(async (e) =>
        {

            var announcementchannel = e.Server.FindChannels("announcements").FirstOrDefault();

            Message[] msgToDel;
            msgToDel = e.Channel.DownloadMessages(1).Result;

            await e.Channel.DeleteMessages(msgToDel);

            await announcementchannel.SendMessage("**Announcement from " + e.User.Name + "**" + " *" + e.GetArg("announceMSG") + "*");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use escape characters to enclose your message in quotes:

```
var msg = "\"hello how are you\"";
```

Comment: I'm trying to make it so you can type in your own announcements, not just "hello how are you" but it only shows the first word.